# how to embed a hubspot form in an external site

Tags: javascript, hubspot

Hi I'm following hubspot's documentation on how to embed a form on an external site

According to documentation, one needs to include the javascript

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
```

and to create the form

```
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({ 
    portalId: '2089699',
    formId: '287337b2-e8a6-4eaa-b293-bbd3d3622d8a'
  });
</script>
```

And that's as far as the documentation goes. I do this and nothing is happening. Seems that at least I would need to tell hubspot *where* to put the form, right?... very strange.

Can anyone enlighten me on this one? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question!

What's needed is the `target` option to tell hubspot where to put the form:

```
<script>
hbspt.forms.create({ 
    portalId: '2089699',
    formId: '287337b2-e8a6-4eaa-b293-bbd3d3622d8a',
    target: '#my_form',
});
</script>
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer, Martin.  It's worth noting the form will render in the same DOM as the script call when a target is not specified.  More extensive form documentation can be found...

... in the HubSpot Forms User Guide: http://knowledge.hubspot.com/forms-user-guide-v2/how-to-replace-an-existing-form-with-a-hubspot-form-on-your-external-website
... in HubSpot's Developer/Form API Docs: http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options
... and in a number of short- and long-form KB articles here: http://knowledge.hubspot.com/search?q=embed%20forms

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the similar task was **create hubspot** form **on DOM ready**.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  hbspt.forms.create({
    css: '',
    target: '#target',
    portalId: 'portal_id',
    formId: 'form_id'
  });
});
</script>
```